# Files in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i have a problem when i am trying to show files download link in django templates

message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "c:\users\ramin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
----------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Writer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Description = models.TextField()
    Image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='PDF/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from . import models

class BookListView(ListView):
    queryset = models.Book.objects.all()
    template_name = 'Book/BookList.html'
```

template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Books List</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for x in object_list %}
        <h2><a href="">{{ x.Title }}</a></h2>
        <img style="width:100px" src="{{ x.Image.url }}">
        <p><a href="{{ x.File.url }}" download="{{ x.Title }}">Download</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

when i click on download link , i can download file successfully but i see this message

Comment: simple_server.py

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem that you use a `.txt` file as the default image

Comment: This was a typing problem when writing the question :)

Comment: this is a weird problem...try to make the link open in a new tab. I don't think it's a code problem

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, assuming that object_name is an object of that model:

```
filename = os.path.basename(object_name.file.name)
response = HttpResponse(object_name.file, content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename

return response
```

See the following part of the Django documentation on sending files directly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment